# What plane type will I need to go transatlantic in Pocket Planes?

Tags: pocket-planes

I'm based in North America and have a bunch of major airports on the Eastern Seaboard.

I'm level 14 and just unlocked the Pearjet, but I still don't have a plane with enough range to make it across the Atlantic.

What's the first plane I'll get that will let me make that crossing?  Or more specifically, what's the range from New York (or Boston) to London (or Lisbon) - the smallest range that'll get me across?

Comment: Madrid is closer than London..

Comment: Also, Madrid is reasonably big (blue dot) and somewhat far away from other European airports, so the price of going there is in itself quite good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to upgrade the Pearjet to level three fuel tanks and then you can fly the new York to London route

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for - didn't want to spend 42 Bux upgrading only to find out the range was just short!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Birtchcraft fully upgraded to fly from Rio De Janiro, class 3 city, to Lagos, class 3 city.

Comment: That's my favored early-transcontinental. (It looks a bit silly to fly NA-SA-Af-Eur, but it works!)

Comment: Is Birchcraft (range 1517) the earliest plane that will go trans-atlantic when upgraded to level 3? Particularly, will an X10 Mapple Pro (range 1050) on level 3 not be able to?

Answer (score 3):

You can buy Goose Bay (Northeast Canada), Nuuk, Reykjavik, and then a coastal European airport. I made it to Europe with Airvans

Comment: +1, this is how I did it.  Unless you get a good load though, it's often not very cost effective.

Answer (score 1):

You can fly the Mohawk (class 1, with no upgrades required) from Recife to Monrovia.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as from level 2 with a one time upgraded griffon. Just buy from America Goose Bay, Nuuk, and Reykjavik. This is the easiest way to do a transatlantic flight in the game. Another option is waiting for Christmas, because in November and December Nimblebit gives you gifts.

Answer (score 0):

Buy Quebec City, Goose Bay, Nuuk, 
Reykjavik, Glasgow. You will be able
 to travel by this route and need a 
class one plane with a range of at least 
882 meters. It will also help to buy out G.B

Answer (score 0):

For me the a great plane to use for transatlantic flights, London to NewYork, would be the Pearjet with fully upgraded fuel tanks, even better if you use the AeroEagle with fully upgraded fuel tanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent Pocket Planes calculator at http://www.therustysnowman.com/proj/pocketplanes.php  which is great at answering questions like:

1. Can plane x fly from city A to city B?
2. If not, is it possible to upgrade the range to make it possible?

It also has a profit calculator for specific routes.  It can be quite handy for figuring out which airports to add to reach a special event city, as well.

It is a little out of date in that it does not have all of the current aircraft (no Mapple, no UAV, no Kringle Kruiser, maybe some others also) but I've found it quite a useful tool.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Griffon  aircraft to Iceland.