# Can you use an Equinox fully upgraded with range to fly from Madrid to New York?

Tags: pocket-planes

I am level 13 and I would really like to know from anyone if I could fully upgrade an equinox with range to fly from Madrid-New York or New York-London? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you wont be able to. You will have to wait till you are level 14 and get the Pearjet and fully up grade that before you can make Madrid/London to New York. This website is helpful to calculate if you can do something before buying planes/airports.

http://therustysnowman.com/proj/pocketplanes.php

Comment: Someone who answered http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75750/what-plane-type-will-i-need-to-go-transatlantic-in-pocket-planes disagrees and says that a Birchcraft level 3 will work. In comparison, Birchcraft level 1 has range 1517 (below Equinox'es range 1600), and Pearjet level 1 has range 1947.